# Cooking 4 lasagnas at same time

Tags: baking

I would like to bake 4 3-lb lasagnas at same time.  Recommended time for one is: 
375 degrees for 55 minutes, remove film and bake an additional 10 minutes for browning.  How much extra time is required and does the temperature need to be changed?

Comment: How full is your oven with those pans in it? How much space is between the top of a pan on the lower rack, and the bottom of the pan above it? And how much space is there around the sides of the pans?

Comment: This answer is going to depend on the oven, and not just how big it is, but how well it maintains temperature. And are these lasagnas frozen? If so, I've seen this experiment done, except that we may have only had 2 frozen lasagnas, and they took forever, ... sorry, I mean "a long time".

Comment: As this is not a direct answer to your question I'll stick it in as a comment, consider (time available) _not_ baking them at the same time, but rather sequentially (or maybe two at a time if that doesn't overcrowd your oven) then allowing them to rest overnight, covered in your fridge, then just reheat them together in 20 minutes +/- and serve. Allowing your lasagna to rest will give you a both distinct layers that won't fall apart on you as you serve and (IMHO) better flavor.

Comment: Thank you for your replies to my question.  I don't feel nearly as intimidated by this event now!

Answer (score 3):

If you can fit all four into one oven and you use *convection*, just use the instructions for one. Like for all foods, you will want to monitor the progress and possibly decide to give it a few extra minutes or to pull it out a moment sooner. But that is a general advice that takes different oven calibrations etc. into account.

If you use a top & bottom heating element *without convection*, you might have to do some juggling as you will probably have two lasagnas on an upper and two on a lower rack. This means they will heat / bake unevenly and you should swap upper and lower at about half the given baking time. You might also have to extend the time by a bit, I'd guestimate perhaps ten minutes or so. But the rule of thumb is bubbly = done, so just have a look. Likewise for the final browning step, plan to swap once, watch to make sure nothing burns.

Comment: The second paragraph is part of why I asked about oven size - if they're crowded and you don't have convection, it gets even worse. You might have to rotate multiple times to really get good results, because the bottom ones can block a lot of heat, and things can end up steamy rather than dry between the two layers.

Answer (score -1):

No change in temperature...probably similar time...timing is not really a critical issue here.  At 55 minutes, carefully lift the foil.  It if it bubbling, it is done.  Remove foil.  Cook until brown.  You could speed browning by carefully placing each pan under the broiler and watching closely.

Comment: I dunno about not changing the time or temperature. I checked the instructions for a 5 pound frozen lasagna and they're 400 F for 90 min, plus 15 min browning.

Comment: OP stated the time and temp...no mention of frozen.  It's not rocket science...just heating lasagna through.  My point is simply that this will not take that much longer than the instructed time...but instructions are irrelevant.  Just observe.  One...or four...it will take an hour...give or take a few minutes.

Comment: @RossRidge a 3 lb is not a 5 lb - and 2 3 pounds are not a 5 (or 6) pound, either - more like one 3 pound. 4 3 pounders do start complicating things if there's no convection, as pointed out by other answers.